# favicon not showing on inner pages of magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, favicon

In one of my magento website I have added favicon using

> magento admin panel > system > configuration > design > HTML head > favicon icon

It was displaying nicely in magento home page but not showing in inner pages. I have changed the current configuration scope to store view and did the same proccess. still it is not working. I hacve cleared caches and re-indexed. but it is not working.

Why is it so? How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: are you talk about in backend ya frontend?

Comment: can you send the view source of inner page, only the <head></head> section

Comment: @Amit Bera I am talking about the frontend...

Answer (score 0):

@ jatinder kumar you may need this only?

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://navaani.in/media/favicon/stores/17/favicon_1.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://navaani.in/media/favicon/stores/17/favicon_1.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://navaani.in/skin/frontend/base/default/images/dresscode_images/favicon.ico">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://navaani.in/skin/frontend/base/default/images/dresscode_images/apple-touch-icon.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="http://navaani.in/skin/frontend/base/default/images/dresscode_images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="http://navaani.in/skin/frontend/base/default/images/dresscode_images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth:200,300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Ask me if you want more. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced similar.  We resolved this (if I'm understanding your issue correctly) by overwriting the default favicon.ico in the root folder with ours.

Note, browser caching in relation to favicon.ico is extremely zealous :)  As such, you will probably only see the change by opening the site in a browser you haven't opened the site in previously or on a different machine.